# How to save Databricks Log Audit as a Table?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, audit, databricks-sql

I want to access the [Databricks Audit Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/account-settings/audit-logs) to check user activity. For example, the number of times that a table was viewed by a user.

I'd like to know if there is any way to get Logs as a Databricks table. I mean, saving the Logs as a table (let's say delta table).

Also, I want it to work continuously; adding new logs to the table when a new event happens (not just one time).

I am not sure if I can use SQL language for this purpose or not (instead of Rest API).

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Are you on Azure? Do you only need it for tables access, or also for something else?

Comment: Yes, I am on Azure. I want to make a report that includes some statistics of Databricks workspace (like the number of times that a table was viewed by a user).

Comment: Could you please provide your approach?

Answer (score 0):

Enable audit logging at database workspace settings as below:

[image]

1.The data of logs is stored at '`/mnt/audit-logs`  so create a table with that location using SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE audit_logs
USING delta
LOCATION '/mnt/audit-logs'
```

[image]

This creates a Delta table named `audit_logs` that points to the `/mnt/audit-logs` directory in the Databricks File System (DBFS).
2.Run a job or execute some code that generates audit logs in Databricks. The audit logs will be written to the `/mnt/audit-logs` directory.
3.Use the following code to continuously update the `audit_logs` Delta table with new audit log events:

```
INSERT INTO audit_logs
SELECT *
FROM delta.`/mnt/audit-logs`
```

[image]

This code inserts the new audit log events into the `audit_logs` Delta table by reading the events from the `/mnt/audit-logs` directory and filtering out any events that have already been processed.
4.Run the code from step 3 periodically (for example, using a Databricks job or a cron job) to continuously update the `audit_logs` Delta table with new audit log events.

In this way you can create audit logs as table by updating continuously.

Comment: Thanks. But, I don't see folder "mnt" on DBFS. There are only two folders: "user", "FilesSore".

Comment: This is not how it works, especially on Azure.